# Cache .NET 6 in Azure Devops

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, pipeline-cache

I'm facing an issue where the pipeline is unable to retrieve the .NET SDK from the cache but instead downloads it on every build.

I'm currently using a Microsoft-hosted agent in Azure DevOps.

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Get .net core 6'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.0.x'
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```

[pipelinelogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smwvI.png)

Am I missing anything in my yml file?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to specify the installationPath argument. I don't see a problem in downloading the dotnet SDK on every build. Unless it's taking quite some time to do so, I'd say it's normal for a Microsoft-hosted agent not to have everything installed. Furthermore, this download might happen because you're always getting a different agent.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of logs.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The agent assigned to your build is restored to original state. So even if you install something there and afterward you will get the same agent it would be clear machine.

There is no way to keep something on Microsoft Hosted agents. For that purpose you should use Self hosted agents.

Comment: Does it mean that there is no way to cache anything using Microsoft hosted agent?

Comment: You can use cache like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops) but not for installed application on build agent. For that purpose you said use self hosted agents.